# Spring Security permitAll() matcher being ignored

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt, spring-webflux

This is based on Spring Security 5.x (latest), being used in a Spring Webflux environment.

I've got a very basic config, attempting to get JWT bearer tokens working.

Config in its entirety:

```
package domain.test.platformapi.config;

import lombok.val;
import domain.test.platformapi.lib.auth.JWTAuthenticationManager;
import domain.test.platformapi.lib.auth.JWTAuthenticationConverter;
import domain.test.platformapi.lib.auth.JWTAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.EnableWebFluxSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.SecurityWebFiltersOrder;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.ServerAuthenticationEntryPointFailureHandler;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.context.ServerSecurityContextRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.context.WebSessionServerSecurityContextRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.util.matcher.PathPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher;

@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig
{
    @Autowired
    private JWTAuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private JWTAuthenticationConverter authenticationConverter;

    private final ServerSecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository = new WebSessionServerSecurityContextRepository();

    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain configure (ServerHttpSecurity httpSecurity)
    {
        return
                httpSecurity
                        .httpBasic().disable()
                        .formLogin().disable()
                        .csrf().disable()
                        .logout().disable()
                        .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                        .securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository)
                        .authorizeExchange()
                            .pathMatchers("v1/auth")
                                .permitAll()
                        .anyExchange()
                            .authenticated()
                        .and().addFilterAt(configureWebFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION)
                .build();
    }

    private AuthenticationWebFilter configureWebFilter ()
    {
        val f = new AuthenticationWebFilter(authenticationManager);

        f.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(new ServerAuthenticationEntryPointFailureHandler(new JWTAuthenticationEntryPoint()));
        f.setAuthenticationConverter(authenticationConverter);

        // Issue is here
        // f.setRequiresAuthenticationMatcher(new PathPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher("v1/user"));

        f.setSecurityContextRepository(securityContextRepository);

        return f;
    }

}
```

Idea is very simple, aside from v1/auth and v1/info, everything else should require authentication and pass through the `AuthenticationWebFilter`. Authentication itself works fine.

Problem is, if `f.setRequiresAuthenticationMatcher(new PathPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher("v1/user"));` (just a test value for now) is omitted, my 'permitAll()` calls above are completely ignored.

EVERYTHING seems to require authentication. I'm likely missing something obvious, anyone have pointers?

I tried to turn on Spring Security debug logging with `logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG` in my application.properties file, but it doesn't seem to generate any real debug logs either.

```
Runtime std{out | err}:

2018-03-06 19:51:11.458  INFO 41896 --- [           main] n.s.p.PlatformApiApplication             : Starting PlatformApiApplication on Bleu with PID 41896 (G:\StudyExpress\platform-api\out\production\classes started by reise in G:\StudyExpress\platform-api)
2018-03-06 19:51:11.460  INFO 41896 --- [           main] n.s.p.PlatformApiApplication             : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-03-06 19:51:11.527  INFO 41896 --- [           main] onfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.AnnotationConfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext@e24ddd0: startup date [Tue Mar 06 19:51:11 JST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (file:/C:/Users/reise/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework/spring-core/5.0.2.RELEASE/45b2958ab3fb022dd29f8b1c553ebf1c75a144aa/spring-core-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2018-03-06 19:51:12.659  INFO 41896 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'arangoDBConfig' of type [domain.test.platformapi.config.ArangoDBConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6e4eb669] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-03-06 19:51:12.711  INFO 41896 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'arango' of type [com.arangodb.ArangoDB$Builder] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-03-06 19:51:12.719  INFO 41896 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'database' of type [java.lang.String] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-03-06 19:51:12.755  INFO 41896 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'customConversions' of type [com.arangodb.springframework.core.convert.ArangoCustomConversions] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-03-06 19:51:12.773  INFO 41896 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'arangoMappingContext' of type [com.arangodb.springframework.core.mapping.ArangoMappingContext] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-03-06 19:51:12.786  INFO 41896 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'arangoConverter' of type [com.arangodb.springframework.core.convert.DefaultArangoConverter] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-03-06 19:51:12.816  INFO 41896 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'arangoTemplate' of type [com.arangodb.springframework.core.template.ArangoTemplate] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-03-06 19:51:12.869  INFO 41896 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cache.annotation.ProxyCachingConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cache.annotation.ProxyCachingConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$141d066d] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-03-06 19:51:12.893  INFO 41896 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$890cb11] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-03-06 19:51:12.911  INFO 41896 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBinderBuilder$ConversionServiceFactory' of type [org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBinderBuilder$ConversionServiceFactory] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-03-06 19:51:13.057  INFO 41896 --- [           main] o.h.v.i.e.ValidatorFactoryImpl           : HV000238: Temporal validation tolerance set to 0.
2018-03-06 19:51:13.079  INFO 41896 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'spring.cache-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheProperties' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-03-06 19:51:13.087  INFO 41896 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'cacheManagerCustomizers' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheManagerCustomizers] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-03-06 19:51:13.090  INFO 41896 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.HazelcastCacheConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.HazelcastCacheConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cb0fc2b7] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-03-06 19:51:13.094  INFO 41896 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hazelcast.HazelcastServerConfiguration$HazelcastServerConfigConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hazelcast.HazelcastServerConfiguration$HazelcastServerConfigConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8f7600e3] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-03-06 19:51:13.098  INFO 41896 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'hazelcastConfig' of type [domain.test.platformapi.config.HazelcastConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b16afb0e] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-03-06 19:51:13.148  INFO 41896 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'config' of type [com.hazelcast.config.Config] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-03-06 19:51:13.176  INFO 41896 --- [           main] c.h.i.AddressPicker                      : [LOCAL] [dev] [3.9] Prefer IPv4 stack is true.
2018-03-06 19:51:13.478  INFO 41896 --- [           main] c.h.i.AddressPicker                      : [LOCAL] [dev] [3.9] Picked [192.168.81.1]:5701, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0,localport=5701], bind any local is true
2018-03-06 19:51:13.486  INFO 41896 --- [           main] c.h.system                               : [192.168.81.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9] Hazelcast 3.9 (20171023 - b29f549) starting at [192.168.81.1]:5701
2018-03-06 19:51:13.486  INFO 41896 --- [           main] c.h.system                               : [192.168.81.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9] Copyright (c) 2008-2017, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
2018-03-06 19:51:13.486  INFO 41896 --- [           main] c.h.system                               : [192.168.81.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9] Configured Hazelcast Serialization version: 1
2018-03-06 19:51:13.656  INFO 41896 --- [           main] c.h.s.i.o.i.BackpressureRegulator        : [192.168.81.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9] Backpressure is disabled
2018-03-06 19:51:14.640  INFO 41896 --- [           main] c.h.i.Node                               : [192.168.81.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9] Creating MulticastJoiner
2018-03-06 19:51:14.730  INFO 41896 --- [           main] c.h.s.i.o.i.OperationExecutorImpl        : [192.168.81.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9] Starting 8 partition threads and 5 generic threads (1 dedicated for priority tasks)
2018-03-06 19:51:14.732  INFO 41896 --- [           main] c.h.i.d.Diagnostics                      : [192.168.81.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9] Diagnostics disabled. To enable add -Dhazelcast.diagnostics.enabled=true to the JVM arguments.
2018-03-06 19:51:14.740  INFO 41896 --- [           main] c.h.c.LifecycleService                   : [192.168.81.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9] [192.168.81.1]:5701 is STARTING
2018-03-06 19:51:16.897  INFO 41896 --- [           main] c.h.system                               : [192.168.81.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9] Cluster version set to 3.9
2018-03-06 19:51:16.898  INFO 41896 --- [           main] c.h.i.c.ClusterService                   : [192.168.81.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9] 

Members {size:1, ver:1} [
    Member [192.168.81.1]:5701 - b70f5ec9-47fb-4ba2-b2bd-511404f44c58 this
]

2018-03-06 19:51:16.916  INFO 41896 --- [           main] c.h.c.LifecycleService                   : [192.168.81.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9] [192.168.81.1]:5701 is STARTED
2018-03-06 19:51:16.930  INFO 41896 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'hazelcastInstance' of type [com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceProxy] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-03-06 19:51:16.935  INFO 41896 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'cacheManager' of type [com.hazelcast.spring.cache.HazelcastCacheManager] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-03-06 19:51:16.936  INFO 41896 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'cacheAutoConfigurationValidator' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration$CacheManagerValidator] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-03-06 19:51:17.098  INFO 41896 --- [           main] s.w.r.r.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/v1/auth],methods=[POST]}" onto public reactor.core.publisher.Mono<domain.test.platformapi.model.opaque.APIResponse> domain.test.platformapi.controller.v1.AuthController.authenticate(domain.test.platformapi.model.Tenant,domain.test.platformapi.model.opaque.AuthRequest)
2018-03-06 19:51:17.102  INFO 41896 --- [           main] s.w.r.r.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/v1/info],methods=[GET]}" onto public reactor.core.publisher.Mono<domain.test.platformapi.model.opaque.APIResponse> domain.test.platformapi.controller.v1.InformationController.resolveAnonymous(org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest,domain.test.platformapi.model.Tenant)
2018-03-06 19:51:17.108  INFO 41896 --- [           main] s.w.r.r.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/v1/student],methods=[GET]}" onto public reactor.core.publisher.Mono<domain.test.platformapi.model.opaque.APIResponse> domain.test.platformapi.controller.v1.StudentController.index()
2018-03-06 19:51:17.109  INFO 41896 --- [           main] s.w.r.r.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/v1/student/test],methods=[GET]}" onto public reactor.core.publisher.Mono<domain.test.platformapi.model.opaque.APIResponse> domain.test.platformapi.controller.v1.StudentController.test(domain.test.platformapi.model.User)
2018-03-06 19:51:17.110  INFO 41896 --- [           main] s.w.r.r.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/v1/student],methods=[POST]}" onto public reactor.core.publisher.Mono<domain.test.platformapi.model.opaque.APIResponse> domain.test.platformapi.controller.v1.StudentController.create(domain.test.platformapi.model.Student)
2018-03-06 19:51:17.111  INFO 41896 --- [           main] s.w.r.r.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/v1/student/{id}],methods=[GET]}" onto public reactor.core.publisher.Mono<domain.test.platformapi.model.opaque.APIResponse> domain.test.platformapi.controller.v1.StudentController.getStudent(java.lang.Long)
2018-03-06 19:51:17.113  INFO 41896 --- [           main] s.w.r.r.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/v1/user],methods=[GET]}" onto public reactor.core.publisher.Mono<domain.test.platformapi.model.opaque.APIResponse> domain.test.platformapi.controller.v1.UserController.index()
2018-03-06 19:51:17.114  INFO 41896 --- [           main] s.w.r.r.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/v1/user/{id}],methods=[GET]}" onto public reactor.core.publisher.Mono<domain.test.platformapi.model.opaque.APIResponse> domain.test.platformapi.controller.v1.UserController.getUser(java.lang.Long)
2018-03-06 19:51:17.478  INFO 41896 --- [           main] .b.a.e.w.r.WebFluxEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/health],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public org.reactivestreams.Publisher<org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.reactive.WebFluxEndpointHandlerMapping$ReadOperationHandler.handle(org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange)
2018-03-06 19:51:17.479  INFO 41896 --- [           main] .b.a.e.w.r.WebFluxEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator/info],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto public org.reactivestreams.Publisher<org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.reactive.WebFluxEndpointHandlerMapping$ReadOperationHandler.handle(org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange)
2018-03-06 19:51:17.479  INFO 41896 --- [           main] .b.a.e.w.r.WebFluxEndpointHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/actuator],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json || application/json]}" onto private java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.util.Map<java.lang.String, org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.Link>> org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.reactive.WebFluxEndpointHandlerMapping.links(org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest)
2018-03-06 19:51:17.510  INFO 41896 --- [           main] o.h.v.i.e.ValidatorFactoryImpl           : HV000238: Temporal validation tolerance set to 0.
2018-03-06 19:51:17.532  INFO 41896 --- [           main] o.s.w.r.r.m.a.ControllerMethodResolver   : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.AnnotationConfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext@e24ddd0: startup date [Tue Mar 06 19:51:11 JST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-03-06 19:51:17.542  INFO 41896 --- [           main] o.s.w.r.r.m.a.ControllerMethodResolver   : Detected @ExceptionHandler methods in validationErrorHandler
2018-03-06 19:51:17.542  INFO 41896 --- [           main] o.s.w.r.r.m.a.ControllerMethodResolver   : Detected @ExceptionHandler methods in genericInputErrorHandler
2018-03-06 19:51:17.543  INFO 41896 --- [           main] o.s.w.r.r.m.a.ControllerMethodResolver   : Detected @ExceptionHandler methods in baseErrorHandler
2018-03-06 19:51:17.543  INFO 41896 --- [           main] o.s.w.r.r.m.a.ControllerMethodResolver   : Detected @ExceptionHandler methods in rootExceptionHandler
2018-03-06 19:51:18.416  INFO 41896 --- [           main] o.h.v.i.e.ValidatorFactoryImpl           : HV000238: Temporal validation tolerance set to 0.
2018-03-06 19:51:18.756  INFO 41896 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-03-06 19:51:18.791  INFO 41896 --- [           main] o.xnio                                   : XNIO version 3.3.8.Final
2018-03-06 19:51:18.797  INFO 41896 --- [           main] o.x.nio                                  : XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.3.8.Final
2018-03-06 19:51:18.847  INFO 41896 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.e.u.UndertowServletWebServer     : Undertow started on port(s) 8443 (https)
2018-03-06 19:51:18.850  INFO 41896 --- [           main] n.s.p.PlatformApiApplication             : Started PlatformApiApplication in 8.424 seconds (JVM running for 9.8)
2018-03-06 19:51:24.993  WARN 41896 --- [   XNIO-1 I/O-8] n.s.p.l.a.JWTAuthenticationConverter     : couldn't find bearer string, will ignore the header
2018-03-06 19:51:24.994  INFO 41896 --- [   XNIO-1 I/O-8] n.s.p.l.a.JWTAuthenticationConverter     : checking authentication for user null
2018-03-06 19:51:25.016 ERROR 41896 --- [   XNIO-1 I/O-8] .a.w.r.e.DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler : Failed to handle request [POST https://127.0.0.1:8443/v1/auth]

org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Invalid token...
    at domain.test.platformapi.lib.auth.JWTAuthenticationConverter.apply(JWTAuthenticationConverter.java:98) ~[classes/:?]
    at domain.test.platformapi.lib.auth.JWTAuthenticationConverter.apply(JWTAuthenticationConverter.java:19) ~[classes/:?]
    at org.springframework.security.web.server.authentication.AuthenticationWebFilter.lambda$filter$1(AuthenticationWebFilter.java:66) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.RELEASE.jar:5.0.0.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:118) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:104) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:1649) ~[reactor-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]...
```

Comment: I think you should chain all the calls to httpSecurity and not have them as separate ones.

Comment: @MateuszMrozewski I'll try that, reporting back shortly.

Comment: I did  that @MateuszMrozewski, no luck though. Same issue.

Comment: Could you update the question with latest code? Also can you try to set the logging level to debug:
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG

Comment: @MateuszMrozewski Sure, did both. Please take a look when you can.

Comment: I managed to get debug logging itself working (was a log4j2 problem), but spring security itself still remains silent.

Log is too big to post on comments, I pastebinned it: https://paste.ee/p/9UT10#FcmeKhNA5iWPknekHrndiXDc9MWON49B

Comment: Upon further debugging, I think it's a case of the filter coming before the antMatchers, i.e: it's on the wrong place in the hierarchy.

The filter denies the user before permitAll ever gets called at all.

Anyone know where the right place for it is?

Comment: Sorry, not sure about that. If you could put part of the source code that reproduces the issue somewhere I would be happy to try to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was because my AuthenticationConverter would actually throw an exception on invalid token (which I have an ExceptionHandler for, that's fine).

This would halt processing of the security flow. `SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION` comes BEFORE the permitAll calls are taken into account, so if the flow is terminated at that filter, nothing further gets done.

This is now resolved. Many thanks to @MateuszMrozewski for the assist.